# Foreign Key not reference to Primary Key in MySQL (phpMyAdmin)

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

This is my parcel table

```
CREATE TABLE parcel (
parcelid INT( 30 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
parcelquantity VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
parcelweight VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,
parceltype VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
parcelpayment VARCHAR( 30 ) NULL ,
receiverid INT(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (  `parcelid` ) ,
FOREIGN KEY (receiverid) REFERENCES shipmentrequest(receiverid)
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

And this is my shipmentrequest table

```
CREATE TABLE shipmentrequest (
receiverid INT( 30 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
receivername VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
receivermobilenumber VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
receiveraddress VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
receivercity VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
receiverpostcode VARCHAR( 10 ) NOT NULL ,
receiverstate VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `receiverid` ) ,
UNIQUE (`receivermobilenumber`)
) ENGINE = MYISAM
```

I wonder why my receiverid in `table parcel` can edit to any value where my primary key `receiverid` in `table shipment request` only have `example value: 1 , 2`

Which line exactly should I change so that foreign-key `receiverid` will only reference to primary key `receiverid` in `table shipment request` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `MYISAM` as engine. That does not support foreign keys. Use `InnoDB`.

```
ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: ohh really? i try first

Comment: But I got this error `#1005 - Can't create table 'pmss.parcel' (errno: 150)`

Comment: `#1005 - Can't create table 'pmss.parcel' (errno: 150) (Details…)` after I click **Details** this is the sentences I received `InnoDB  Documentation

Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys

[ Variables | Buffer Pool | InnoDB Status ]`

Comment: But I saw this InnoDB does not currently support foreign keys for tables with user-defined partitioning. This means that no user-partitioned InnoDB table may contain foreign key references or columns referenced by foreign keys.

**InnoDB allows a foreign key constraint to reference a non-unique key. This is an InnoDB extension to standard SQL.** But my receiverid is primary key which means also unique right?

Comment: Yes, it is unique. And the table creation works in the fiddle.

Comment: U try both of my table creation in my question, It have erros on SQL Fiddle

Comment: I try my create table parcel in mysql fiddle it give me the errors which I mention in above comment :`Schema Creation Failed: Can't create table 'db_2_9b397.parcel' (errno: 150): `

Comment: I found the error happen, coz my previous table was using **ENGINE = MYISAM** which is 100% cannot match which my other table with **ENGINE = InnoDB**, I remove all table and change the engine to InnoDB and everythings works fine!  Thanks for your help